# PHP logging solution?

Tags: php, logging

i am looking for a php logging solution like log4net. do you know any solution or can you suggest anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Zend_Log for application logging

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.html

Comment: If i want to use Zend_Log, will i install or configure all zend framework? Or can i just use zend_log php file?

Comment: Zend_Log doesn't have any dependencies, so no you don't need the whole framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really looking forward for [apache log4php](http://incubator.apache.org/log4php/index.html) which is currently under incubation process. So far apache logging services provided to be the best, I've used it in java, c++, .net and even python. Good stuff, pretty much of a solid standard these days. Hopefully the php one will pass too. Does anyone know when they are planning to finish with the incubation?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am looking for log4php. But they did not make any release yet. Because of that i asked here. I think there are lots of php programmers that are waiting for log4php.

Answer (score 0):

How about

http://pear.php.net/package/Log